# Sampling from a distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling, programming

In many cases we use sampling from a distribution. Also in programming languages they implement it.

But I wonder now what is the process of generating a sample from a probability distribution?

What happens behind the scene that given the parameters a model, a function returns a sample?

Also how can I know more on this topic? I want to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a few methods to sample from any distribution! To begin with, one has to start with a so-called random number generator i.e one has to be able to sample from the standard uniform distribution to access the methods to sample from let's say a normal distribution. I can name some methods and I suggest reading the Wikipedia articles to start with.[rejection sampling](http://Rejection%20sampling), [Importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling), [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

I also think that those are the most well-known and used. Again for all the methods, a basic random generator is required.

Comment: RNG to do what? Can you clearly explain that part?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Intuitions, This should answer your question.
In essence using this method you can sample from any distribution given that you can derive its inverse and that you can sample from the Uniform$[0,1]$